# CLLocationManager freeze my app when returning from background state?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, core-location, cllocationmanager

I'm using CLLocationManager in a different views of my app and when returning from background state some kind of freezing for about 2 to 3 seconds, not responding to user interaction.

**In my AppDelegate i'm using this code:**

```
   _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init]; 
   // Get the location if the user
    if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) 
    {
       [self.locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters];
       [self.locationManager setDistanceFilter:50];
       [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
```

**In Other View i'm using this code:**

```
    _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) 
    {
       [self.locationManager setDelegate:self];
       [self.locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters];
       [self.locationManager setDistanceFilter:50];
       [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }

      // Delegate
    - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
   {   
         // Set the map view to the current location
         MKCoordinateSpan span;
         span.latitudeDelta = 0.01;
         span.longitudeDelta = 0.02;

         MKCoordinateRegion region;
         region.span = span;
         region.center = newLocation.coordinate;

         [_mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

    }
```

Comment: Do you need locations when you are in background? Can you just stop updating the location then?

Comment: This question lacks detail. I use CLLocationManager and don't see an issue. Have you isolated what line/s of code is causing the delay? What happens if you don't turn on locationmanger?

Comment: If i don't turn on the location manager, i don't have any issue

Answer (score 0):

Use these notifications to turn on (locationManager startUpdatingLocation) and turn off (locationManager stopUpdatingLocation) when the app enters enters background and becomes active:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(start) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(stop) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
```

Comment: In whatever class handles your didUpdateLocation I would think.

Comment: Have any luck with that change?

Comment: No, i haven't i still have the same thing